# Why can't the button style in thems.xml be applied?

Tags: android, styles, themes

I am now trying to apply the new font to the `entire application`.

By the way, although the `style tag` was defined in the `themes.xml`, the `textView` was applied collectively, but the font was not applied to other views such as buttons and chips.

I just had to `style=""` the button directly, but it's too cumbersome.

And the style cannot be applied directly to the `Chip`.

what's the reason? Is this a bug?

***themes.xml***

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.WriteWeight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_green_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewFont</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="chipStyle">@style/ChipStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextViewFont" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_font_family</item>
        <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
        <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/light_green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ChipStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
        <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

***roboto_font_family.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- thin -->
    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto_thin"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="100"
        app:font="@font/roboto_thin"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="100"/>

    <!-- light -->
    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto_light"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="300"
        app:font="@font/roboto_light"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="300"/>

    <!-- regular -->
    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_black"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

***fragment_body_part_dialog.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light_green">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_dialog">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcy_part"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            tools:listitem="@layout/body_part_item"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="start"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_green"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

***fragment_workout_list_dialog.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/routine_list_recycler"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never">
        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/routine_chipgroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:chipSpacingHorizontal="10dp"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            style="@style/ChipStyle">
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_back"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="BACK"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_chest"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="CHEST"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_leg"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="LEG"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_sholuder"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="SHOULDER"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_biceps"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="BICEPS"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_triceps"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TRICEP"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_abs"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="ABS"
                app:rippleColor="@color/light_green"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"/>
        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/light_green"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_scroll"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/routine_list_recycler"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/routine_list_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontal_bar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set button style in your Material theme:

```
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>

   <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
       ...
```

Comment: OMG..Thank you it does work.. But chip is still not worked..how should i do?

Comment: you set  the chip style directly in the view, style="@style/CustomChipChoice", so it will don't get from the theme

Comment: oh yeah, that's my mistake. but i delete `style="@style/CustomChipChoice"` this code, the result is the same.